# Possible solution for same flipped triangle

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

/*The code below gives you the first triangle of *, I would like to know to print the same triangle but flipped like in the description below.*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j,rows;
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",&rows);
   for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)
   {
      for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
      {
         printf("* ");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

How would you change the code above to get this triangle instead:

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to print the other triangle?

Comment: You can print spaces.

Comment: How you you print spaces...??

Comment: `printf(" ");` and done

Comment: You can also use `putchar(' ');` to print single spaces, and `putchar('*');` to print single asterisks.  Use appropriate size loops.

Comment: You could also exploit the crap out of `printf` format capabilities and just do it with one loop [**like this**](http://ideone.com/V4bOSZ).

Answer (score 0):

Well this code is what you need

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
    int a,b,n;
    for(n=0;n<7;n++)
      {         
        for(a=7;a>=n;a--)
          {
            printf(" ");        
          }
        for(b=0;b<n;b++)
          {                 
            printf("*");
          }
        printf("\n");
      }
    return 0;       
  }
```